# Sending message via Python + xmpppy: AttributeError in minimal example

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-module, xmpppy

I found in a related question a minimal example to send a message via xmpp(py); see below. But when I execute the script I get the following error:

```
   client = xmpp.Client('gmail.com')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Client'
```

I'm working with Eclipse and PyDev, and xmpppy should definitely be installed. The Interpreter includes /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ and when looking there I find

```
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xmpppy-0.5.0rc1-py2.7.egg
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xmpppy-0.5.0rc1-py2.7.egg/xmpp
```

help('modules') also shows me the xmpp module. When using the autocomplete function (CTRL + SPACE) in Eclipse/PyDev I can actually 'see' the client. Still, I get the AttributeError. I guess I'm missing something really stupid here.

Thanks,

Christian

```
import xmpp

username = 'username'
passwd = 'password'
to='name@example.com'
msg='hello :)'

client = xmpp.Client('gmail.com')
client.connect(server=('talk.google.com',5223))
client.auth(username, passwd, 'botty')
client.sendInitPresence()
message = xmpp.Message(to, msg)
message.setAttr('type', 'chat')
client.send(message)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've named a script `xmpp.py`. You're accidentally `import`ing it instead of the real `xmpp` module.

Rename the script and everything should work fine.

Comment: I knew it was something like that :). Sorry, for my stupidity and thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @agf: i renamed the file but still it says same